# Summation of a Bernoulli distribution Question

Tags: statistics, summation

Can anyone help me figure out how I would solve this?
$$\sum_{i=0}^1p^i*(1-p)^{1-i}*e^{ti}$$

Comment: Thank you in advance!

Comment: Channelling Sarah with a minor correction: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^1 p^i \cdot(1-p)^{1-i} \cdot e^{ti}= p^0 \cdot(1-p)^{1} \cdot e^{0} + p^1\cdot(1-p)^{0} \cdot e^{t}$ which you can simplify